# Creating a beautiful chart inside python kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, graph, charts, kivy, kivymd

I want to create a beautiful chart inside my kivymd program, some like this:

[image: Chart from svg.charts]

I loved this design of chart, because have good colors and transparency, but I don't know how I can create a chart like this inside kivy or kivymd.

It was created by svg.charts, I tried to show it inside a Svg widget from kivy, but don't works. And I tried convert it to png too, using pylunasvg, but the background color turned black...

I saw that have kivy garden charts, that is very similar to matplotlib, but I think that its uggly, because I don't know how fill it with transparency or how to create a card with the lines titles. It's the chart image in the github:

[image: Kivy garden graph charts]

I saw too the akivymd chart, but it have a lot of colors and will be tiring the user. The print from the example application of the akivymd repository:

[image: Akivymd chart]

I don't know what to do anymore, somebody have a tip that how I create a chart like the first inside kivy?

**EDITED**

This was the file that the conversion created:

[image: The converted file]

It's my conversion method:

```py
from PIL import Image as pImage
from pylunasvg import Document
from numpy import array
from typing import Optional, Union

def svg_to_image(svg_content: str,
                 savedir: Optional[str] = None,
                 filename: Optional[str] = None) -> Union[str, type(pImage)]:
    document = Document.loadFromData(svg_content)
    bitmap = document.renderToBitmap()

    img = pImage.fromarray(array(bitmap, copy=False))

    if savedir is not None:
        if filename is not None:
            if filename.endswith('.png'):
                _dir = join(savedir, filename)
            else:
                _dir = join(savedir, filename + '.png')
        elif savedir.endswith('.png'):
            _dir = savedir
        else:
            raise ValueError('Argument filename is None')
        img.save(_dir, format='png')
        return _dir
    else:
        return img
```

**RESUMED**

I will resume my question, **how the better way to show a beautiful chart inside kivy?**

Some like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you sure that your conversion to png created black background? Perhaps is was just a transparent background.

Comment: Yeah, I open with three programs and try inside kivy too, I will paste the file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, such I don't find any good graph library, I created my own widget. It's took a while, but I got it. I published this widgets inside [my repository](https://github.com/RicardoDazzling/kivyplots/), and I expect that it help another peoples like me, I used kivy 2.2.0.dev0 and kivymd 1.2.0.dev0. This is a print from the LineChart:

[image: Chart from svg.charts]

Thank you everybody that tried to help me!